# Upserting a record using meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have a collection `balances` that i want to update or insert if that record does not exist.

When i run the method like this,

```
Meteor.methods({
    upsertfun:function(userid){
    //let balance = 0;
        //var balance  = Balances.findOne({userid:userid}).balance;
        //if(balance == null){balance = 0;}
        var paypal_gross = 200;
        //var updatedbalance = parseInt(balance) + parseInt(paypal_gross);
        Balances.update({
                 userid: userid,
                 balance: 30
              }, {
                 $set: {
                    userid: userid,
                    balance: 543
                 }
              }, {
                  upsert: true
              })
    }
});
```

i am able to upsert but fails when i introduce variables.

This is how it would look with variables in

```
Meteor.methods({
    upsertfun:function(userid){
    //let balance = 0;
        var balance  = Balances.findOne({userid:userid}).balance;
        if(balance == null){balance = 0;}
        var paypal_gross = 200;
        var updatedbalance = parseInt(balance) + parseInt(paypal_gross);
        Balances.update({
                 userid: userid,
                 balance: balance
              }, {
                 $set: {
                    userid: userid,
                    balance: updatedbalance
                 }
              }, {
                  upsert: true
              })
    }
});
```

For some reason, this keeps throwing error 500,server error. What can i do to fix this?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is a bit dirty. Pay attention to object chains like `Balances.findOne().balance`. When `findOne()` returns null, you get a fatal error because you try to access an undefined property of null object.

```
var balance_item = Balances.findOne({ userid: userid });
var balance = 0;
if (balance_item) {
    balance = balance_item.balance;
}
var paypal_gross = 200;
var updatedbalance = parseInt(balance) + parseInt(paypal_gross);
Balances.update({
    userid: userid,
    balance: balance
}, {
    $set: {
    userid: userid,
    balance: updatedbalance
    }
}, {
    upsert: true
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I had forgotten to check if record exists first

```
Meteor.methods({
    upsertfun:function(userid){
         var selector = {
            "userid": userid
            };

           var this_exists = Balances.find(selector, {limit: 1}).count() > 0;

           if(this_exists == true) {
           console.log('exists');
           } else {
        Balances.insert({userid:userid,balance:0});
           }

    //let balance = 0;
        var balance  = Balances.findOne({userid:userid}).balance;
        if(balance == null){balance = 0;}
        var paypal_gross = 200;
        var updatedbalance = parseInt(balance) + parseInt(paypal_gross);
        Balances.update({
                 userid: userid,
                 balance: balance
              }, {
                 $set: {
                    userid: userid,
                    balance: updatedbalance
                 }
              }, {
                  upsert: true
              })
    }
});
```

Comment: You can use the upsert method too so you don't need to check if it exists.

http://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-upsert

Answer (score 0):

The upsert method can take 4 arguments: queryDocument, changeDocument, options, callback.  The options argument can be {upsert: true}